# Run PowerShell script in folder that it lives in

Tags: powershell, file-extension, get-childitem

I have a question that I think will be relatively simple to answer. I have a script that will change blank file extensions to be PDFs. Here it is:

```
$directory = 'C:\Test\Files'

Get-ChildItem -File $directory | Where-Object { -Not $_.Extension } | Foreach-Object {
  $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.Name).pdf"
}
```

It works just fine, but I need it to only run in the directory/folder it lives in. For example, if I have it in my documents folder, it would only run in my documents folder and not make any changes to any other folders, including subfolders in the documents folder. Is this possible, and what would it look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On PowerShell v3 or newer use

```
$directory = $PSScriptRoot
```

On older versions use

```
$directory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the $myinvocation automatic variable

```
$invoke = $myinvocation.mycommand.path
$directory = Split-Path $invoke
Get-ChildItem -File $directory | Where-Object { -Not $_.Extension } | Foreach-Object {$_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.Name).pdf"
}
```